# Writing a custom aggregate function

Tags: postgresql, aggregate-functions, plpgsql

Lately I've been practicing and studying PL/pgSQL. I'm stuck on creating a custom aggregate function.

The code below works just fine, but I'm not able to write an aggregate function of this type:

```
SELECT my_aggregate_function(column) from table;
```

Here is the code of the "partially working custom aggregate":

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION searchMinValue (numeric[]) RETURNS numeric   AS $$
  DECLARE 
     i numeric;
     minVal numeric;
  BEGIN
    minVal := $1[1];
    IF ARRAY_LENGTH($1,1) > 0 THEN --Checking whether the array is empty or not
  <<confrontoMinimo>>
   FOREACH i IN ARRAY $1 LOOP --Looping through the entire array, passed as parameter
       IF minVal >= i THEN
           minVal := i;
       END IF;
   END LOOP confrontoMinimo;
   ELSE
    RAISE NOTICE 'Invalid parameter % passed to the aggregate function',$1;
   --Raising exception if the parameter passed as argument points to null.
   RAISE EXCEPTION 'Cannot find Max value. Parameter % is null', $1
   USING HINT = 'You cannot pass a null array! Check the passed parameter';
END IF;
RETURN minVal;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE AGGREGATE searchMinValueArray (numeric)
(
sfunc = array_append,
stype = numeric[],
finalfunc = searchMinValue,
initCond = '{}'
); 

 with w(v) as (select 5 union all select 2 union all select 3)
 select min(v) "Normal Aggregate", searchMinValueArray(v) "My Customed Aggregate" from w;
```

As I said before, I'd like to call my custom aggregate function in this way:

```
SELECT my_aggregate_function(column) from table;
```

where the table is `Customers` and the column is `salary` of type `numeric`.

Comment: Can you describe the problem/error you are encountering?

Comment: I've run your code it's work , what is your problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are fundamentally doing the right thing, but there are still some problems with your implementation:

1. Your aggregate will error out if the table is empty. Rather, it should return `NULL`.
2. If the first value you are aggregating is `NULL`, your aggregate will do the wrong thing. if

   ```
   minVal := $1[1];
   ```

   sets `minVal` to `NULL`, then all future comparisons `minVal >= i` will *not* be `TRUE`, and the end result will be `NULL`, which is not what you want.
3. You collect all values in an array, which will become quite big if you aggregate many rows. First this puts you in danger of running out of memory with the array, and then the performance of the aggregate will not be as good as it could be.

   It is much better to perform the comparison in `SFUNC`: start with `INITCOND = NULL`, use `STYPE = numeric` and perform the aggregation whenever a you process a new value. The relevant part of `SFUNC` would look like this:

   ```
   IF $1 IS NULL OR $1 > $2
       RETURN $2;
   ELSE
       RETURN $1;
   END IF;
   ```

   That way you don't need a `FINALFUNC` at all.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware that if my array becomes big, my memory risks to run out. But in the code that you wrote, you pass two parameters: **$1 and $2**. What is $2?

Comment: I wrote parts of a possible "state transition function" (`SFUNC` in `CREATE AGGREGATE`). See the documentation.